# Using stomp.py to pick up messages and quit

Tags: python, multithreading, stomp, stomp.py

I'm wondering how to use [stomp.py](http://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/index.html) client in a *pick-process-finish* manner. This means: start; connect; check the queue; pick messages; process them; disconnect; finish.

The lib seems to be designed for indefinitely running clients which listen on arriving messages and process them. The main thread has to somehow remain running/connected while the listener thread processes the incoming messages.

It strikes me the examples are happily using `time.sleep(X)` to keep the main thread up and running. This is not really viable since there is no guarantee the listener thread finishes its work before the sleep ends. With a static sleep you can't guarantee you can process all messages before you disconnect, right? ACKs are fine and usable but still.

Is there a way to keep the main thread up until the listener finishes its work?

Comment: This question could be closed for 2 different reasons actually. First, it is opinion based since it is asking an open-ended question about how to keep the main thread up while the listener finishes. Questions eliciting opinion-based answers are off topic. Second, it's asking for recommendations for another STOMP client. This is also off-topic.

Comment: @JustinBertram The first question is perfectly fine for Stack Overflow ("how can I do X" is our bread and butter). The second can be edited out, which I've done now.

Comment: To be fair, the question is _not_ "how can I do X" but rather "is there a way to do X." I doubt @Yuri is looking for a simple "yes" or "no" here so the "how" is implied, but the ambiguity is problematic since it is nonetheless open for interpretation. In any case, "how can I do X" is not universally acceptable if the question is ultimately eliciting opinions (e.g. "how can I best skin a cat?"). In this case, there are a handful of ways to keep the main thread up until the listener finishes. Which way is "correct" for this use-case? There aren't enough details to know so it's opinion-based.